# Add button to keyboard toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have UIWebView integrated in my app. When I'm clicking on text fields inside it keyboard with 3 toolbar button called (<, > and Done).

[image: toolbar]

Is it any way so add custom buttons to that toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom UIView  to instead the inputAccessoryView. After that, add your custom buttons on the custom UIView。

Comment: And is it any way to keep old buttons too? If I create custom view I will destroy default functionality?